# how to test if hdecode is running correctly

Tags: speech-recognition, speech

i am trying to run sailalign. it requires htk and hdecode to be installed. when i tested sail align i got the following error

> ~/SailAlign-1.10$ sail_align -i support/data/timit_5.wav -t support/data/timit_5.txt -w support/data/test/timit_sample_test -e timit_sample_test -c config/timit_alignment.cfg 
>   [FATAL] (/usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/SailTools/SailHtkWrapper.pm line 408) HVite failed:  ERROR [+6510]  LOpen: Unable to open label file support/data/test/timit_sample_test/asr/timit_5.0-12880.rec
>
> FATAL ERROR - Terminating program
>   /home/mxa129730/SailAlign-1.10/bin/HVite Illegal division by zero at
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/SailTools/AlignSpeech.pm line 395.

contacting the developers of sailalign they mentioned the problem was probably with hdecode 
i made sure both htk and hdecode are installed correctly and i even tested htk with the HTKDemo but i can't find a way to test hdecode

Comment: The HVite issue is simply due to the file not being generated as suggested by the log. You need to check earlier messages to understand what was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the HDecode directly with this command (you will need to change the path appropriately for your test):

```sh
sail_align/bin/HDecode -T 1 -C support/test/local/asr.cfg -t 150.0 -o S -p -4.0 -s 15.0 -H sail_align/models/ac_models/english/htk/wsj_all_10000_32/hmmdefs -H sail_align/models/ac_models/english/htk/wsj_all_10000_32/macros -l support/test/local/asr -S support/test/local/timit_5.seg -w support/test/local/lm/timit_5.lm support/test/local/dictionary sail_align/models/ac_models/english/htk/wsj_all_10000_32/tiedlist
```

If that does not work, please try to use the HDecode binary from SailAlign author: http://cvsp.cs.ntua.gr/~nassos/HDecode

If that does not work either, please try to reinstall SailAlign.